# BizTalk Schema - Corrupted after changing schema properties (even after setting them back)

Tags: schema, biztalk, corrupt

I have a schema that works.  It validates correctly, it validates the instance flat file correctly, and all is well.  I then decide to try some of the schema properties settings like, "Allow Early Termination," and the schema no longer validates, nut instead results in the:
 "error BEC2004: Unexpected end of stream while looking for:" error.  I then set the setting back to No and save my files, but I get the same setting.  I then tried rebuilding the solution and get the same issue.  The only way that I have found to "fix" my schema is to replace it with an original working version (I am glad I made the copy) or to rebuild it from scratch.

This has happened with a few schemas and resulted in my search for answers to the "error BEC2004: Unexpected end of stream while looking for:" error (for schemas that otherwise worked before changing a setting or two, and then turning them back).  The schema settings seem to change back to their original state in the actual XML file when opened from notepad++ or sublime-text, but just wont validate anymore.

**Has anyone else had this problem? --Know what causes this problem? -- or have any suggestions for how to prevent this issue from bothering me anymore?**

I am unsure if this is a BizTalk issue, IDE, or some other cause.

Side note: I have BizTalk Server and Services SDK's installed and was wondering if they are known to interfere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I seem to have figured it out.  I have two fields for "Input Instance Filename," as you can see above.  I think that one is for BizTalk services and the other for BizTalk server, but they are not labeled as so.  Not knowing which field to use, I had both filled in.  After only filling in the two seen above (for input and output) and setting the "Validate Instance Input Type" to Native, the schema validated perfectly.

I had Native set before, but the BizTalk Services "Input Instance Filename" seemed to have been overriding the "Validate Instance Input Type" for the BizTalk Server field.

To sum it up: If you are validating a schema for BizTalk Server and Services, make sure you set the "Validate Instance Input Type" to native **after entering one** "Input Instance Filename".  Then add the other "Input Instance Filename", and then make sure that Native is still set.

Note: This is for Flat File schema validation

I hope this helps anyone else with this issue.

**Update:**  After restructuring my solution, I ran into this issue again.  I found that simply removing all of the paths to instances (input and output), rebuilding the solution, re-entering the paths and instance type, and then validating worked.  When I rebuilt with no paths entered, the duplicate fields disappeared, allowing me to set the correct paths and type.

Comment: Please mark your answer as The Answer by clicking on the check sign :-)

Comment: I will, it won't let me do so until 16 more hours. :)